# Get default value from input in react

Tags: reactjs

I've the following code in the [editor here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-ezhl7t)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import "jqwidgets-scripts/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css";
import JqxButton from "jqwidgets-scripts/jqwidgets-react-tsx/jqxbuttons";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import JqxWindow from "jqwidgets-scripts/jqwidgets-react-tsx/jqxwindow";
import JqxInput from "jqwidgets-scripts/jqwidgets-react-tsx/jqxinput";

import JqxChart, {
  IChartProps
} from "jqwidgets-scripts/jqwidgets-react-tsx/jqxchart";
import JqxGrid, {
  IGridProps,
  jqx
} from "jqwidgets-scripts/jqwidgets-react-tsx/jqxgrid";
import JqxTabs from "jqwidgets-scripts/jqwidgets-react-tsx/jqxtabs";
import JqxDropDownList, {
  IDropDownListProps
} from "jqwidgets-scripts/jqwidgets-react-tsx/jqxdropdownlist";

interface AppProps {}
interface AppState {
  name: string;
}
interface IProps extends IGridProps {
  rendertoolbar1: IGridProps["rendertoolbar"];
  dropdownlistSource: IDropDownListProps["source"];
}

class App extends Component<{}, IProps> {
  private myTabs = React.createRef<JqxTabs>();
  private gridElement = React.createRef<HTMLDivElement>();
  private gridElementTwo = React.createRef<HTMLDivElement>();
  private myGrid = React.createRef<JqxGrid>();
  private myGrid2 = React.createRef<JqxGrid>();
  private myWindow = React.createRef<JqxWindow>();
  private myWindowTWO = React.createRef<JqxWindow>();
  private date = React.createRef<JqxInput>();
  private sAndP500 = React.createRef<JqxInput>();

  constructor(props: {}) {
    super(props);
    this.saveBtn = this.saveBtn.bind(this);
    this.cancelBtn = this.cancelBtn.bind(this);
    this.saveBtntwo = this.saveBtn.bind(this);
    this.cancelBtntwo = this.cancelBtn.bind(this);

    const rendertoolbar = (toolbar: any): void => {
      const addRowClick = () => {
        //const datarow = this.generaterow();
        //this.myGrid.current!.addrow(null, datarow);
        this.myWindow.current!.open();
      };

      const addRowClickTwo = () => {
        //const datarow = this.generaterow();
        //this.myGrid.current!.addrow(null, datarow);
        this.myWindowTWO.current!.open();
      };

      ReactDOM.render(
        <div style={{ margin: "5px" }}>
          <div
            id="buttonContainer2"
            style={{ float: "left", marginLeft: "5px" }}
          >
            <JqxButton
              onClick={addRowClickTwo}
              width={125}
              value={"Add New NASDAQ"}
            />
          </div>
        </div>,
        toolbar[0]
      );
    };

    const rendertoolbar1 = (toolbar: any): void => {
      const addRowClick = () => {
        //const datarow = this.generaterow();
        //this.myGrid.current!.addrow(null, datarow);
        this.myWindow.current!.open();
      };

      const addRowClickTwo = () => {
        //const datarow = this.generaterow();
        //this.myGrid.current!.addrow(null, datarow);
        this.myWindowTWO.current!.open();
      };

      ReactDOM.render(
        <div style={{ margin: "5px" }}>
          <div id="buttonContainer1" style={{ float: "left" }}>
            <JqxButton
              onClick={addRowClick}
              width={135}
              value={"Add New Us Index"}
            />
          </div>
        </div>,
        toolbar[0]
      );
    };

    this.state = {
      rendertoolbar,
      rendertoolbar1,
      // dropdownlistSource: ["Affogato", "Americano", "Bicerin", "Breve"]
      dropdownlistSource: [
        { value: 0, label: "Affogato" },
        { value: 1, label: "Americano" },
        { value: 2, label: "Bicerin" },
        { value: 3, label: "Breve" }
      ]
      //source: new jqx.dataAdapter(source)
    };
  }
  public render() {
    return (
      <JqxTabs
        ref={this.myTabs}
        // @ts-ignore
        width={400}
        height={560}
        initTabContent={this.initWidgets}
        onSelected={this.onTabSelected}
      >
        <JqxWindow
          ref={this.myWindow}
          width={250}
          height={230}
          resizable={false}
          isModal={false}
          autoOpen={false}
          modalOpacity={"0.01"}
          position={{ x: 68, y: 368 }}
        >
          <div>Add New US Indexes</div>
          <div style={{ overflow: "hidden" }}>
            <table>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td align={"right"}>Date:</td>
                  <td align={"left"}>
                    <JqxInput ref={this.date} width={150} height={23} />
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align={"right"}>S & P 500:</td>
                  <td align={"left"}>
                    <JqxInput ref={this.sAndP500} width={150} height={23} />
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align={"right"}>DropDownList:</td>
                  <td align={"left"}>
                    <JqxDropDownList
                      width={100}
                      height={20}
                      source={this.state.dropdownlistSource}
                      selectedIndex={0}
                    />
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align={"right"} />
                  <td style={{ paddingTop: "10px" }} align={"right"}>
                    <JqxButton
                      style={{ display: "inline-block", marginRight: "5px" }}
                      onClick={this.saveBtn}
                      width={50}
                    >
                      Save
                    </JqxButton>
                    <JqxButton
                      style={{ display: "inline-block", marginRight: "5px" }}
                      onClick={this.cancelBtn}
                      width={50}
                    >
                      Cancel
                    </JqxButton>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </JqxWindow>
        <JqxWindow
          ref={this.myWindowTWO}
          width={250}
          height={230}
          resizable={false}
          isModal={false}
          autoOpen={false}
          modalOpacity={"0.01"}
          position={{ x: 68, y: 368 }}
        >
          <div>Add New NASDAQ</div>
          <div style={{ overflow: "hidden" }}>
            <table>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td align={"right"}>Date:</td>
                  <td align={"left"}>
                    <JqxInput ref={this.date} width={150} height={23} />
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align={"right"}>S & P 500:</td>
                  <td align={"left"}>
                    <JqxInput ref={this.sAndP500} width={150} height={23} />
                  </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td align={"right"} />
                  <td style={{ paddingTop: "10px" }} align={"right"}>
                    <JqxButton
                      style={{ display: "inline-block", marginRight: "5px" }}
                      onClick={this.saveBtntwo}
                      width={50}
                    >
                      Save
                    </JqxButton>
                    <JqxButton
                      style={{ display: "inline-block", marginRight: "5px" }}
                      onClick={this.cancelBtntwo}
                      width={50}
                    >
                      Cancel
                    </JqxButton>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </JqxWindow>
        <ul>
          <li style={{ marginLeft: 30 }}>
            <div style={{ height: 20, marginTop: 5 }}>
              <div style={{ float: "left" }}>
                <img width="16" height="16" src="./../images/catalogicon.png" />
              </div>
              <div
                style={{
                  marginLeft: 4,
                  verticalAlign: "middle",
                  textAlign: "center",
                  float: "left"
                }}
              >
                US Indexes
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div style={{ height: 20, marginTop: 5 }}>
              <div style={{ float: "left" }}>
                <img width="16" height="16" src="./../images/pieicon.png" />
              </div>
              <div
                style={{
                  marginLeft: 4,
                  verticalAlign: "middle",
                  textAlign: "center",
                  float: "left"
                }}
              >
                NASDAQ compared to S&P 500
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div style={{ overflow: "hidden" }}>
          <div id="jqxGrid" ref={this.gridElement} />
          <div style={{ marginTop: 10, height: "15%" }} />
        </div>
        <div style={{ overflow: "hidden" }}>
          <div id="jqxGrid2" ref={this.gridElementTwo} />
          <div style={{ marginTop: 10, height: "15%" }} />
        </div>
      </JqxTabs>
    );
  }
  private initGrid = () => {
    const source = {
      datafields: [{ name: "Date" }, { name: "S&P 500" }, { name: "NASDAQ" }],
      datatype: "csv",
      //url: './assets/nasdaq_vs_sp500.txt'
      localdata: `1/2/2014,1831.98,4143.07
1/3/2014,1831.37,4131.91
1/6/2014,1826.77,4113.68
1/7/2014,1837.88,4153.18
1/8/2014,1837.49,4165.61
1/9/2014,1838.13,4156.19
1/10/2014,1842.37,4174.67
1/13/2014,1819.2,4113.3
1/14/2014,1838.88,4183.02
1/15/2014,1848.38,4214.88
1/16/2014,1845.89,4218.69
1/17/2014,1838.7,4197.58
1/21/2014,1843.8,4225.76
1/22/2014,1844.86,4243
1/23/2014,1828.46,4218.88
1/24/2014,1790.29,4128.17
1/27/2014,1781.56,4083.61
1/28/2014,1792.5,4097.96
1/29/2014,1774.2,4051.43
1/30/2014,1794.19,4123.13
1/31/2014,1782.59,4103.88
2/3/2014,1741.89,3996.96
2/4/2014,1755.2,4031.52
2/5/2014,1751.64,4011.55
2/6/2014,1773.43,4057.12
2/7/2014,1797.02,4125.86`
    };

    const dataAdapter = new jqx.dataAdapter(source, {
      async: false,
      loadError: (xhr: any, status: any, error: any) => {
        console.log(xhr, status, error);
        //alert('Error loading "' + source.url + '" : ' + error);
      }
    });

    const columns: IGridProps["columns"] = [
      { cellsformat: "d", datafield: "Date", text: "Date", width: 250 },
      { datafield: "S&P 500", text: "S&P 500", width: 150 },
      { datafield: "NASDAQ", text: "NASDAQ" }
    ];
    const grid = (
      <JqxGrid
        ref={this.myGrid}
        width={"100%"}
        height={400}
        source={dataAdapter}
        columns={columns}
        showtoolbar={true}
        rendertoolbar={this.state.rendertoolbar1}
      />
    );
    render(grid, this.gridElement.current!);
  };
  private saveBtn(): void {
    const row = {
     sAndP500:this.sAndP500.current!.getOptions('value'),
     date:this.date.current!.getOptions('value')

    }
    console.log("Testing Row inside SaveBtn");
    console.log(row);
    this.myWindow.current!.hide();
  }

  private cancelBtn(): void {

    this.myWindow.current!.hide();
  }

  private initGrid2 = () => {
    const source = {
      datafields: [{ name: "Date" }, { name: "S&P 500" }, { name: "NASDAQ" }],
      datatype: "csv",
      //url: './assets/nasdaq_vs_sp500.txt'
      localdata: `1/2/2014,1831.98,4143.07
1/3/2014,1831.37,4131.91
1/6/2014,1826.77,4113.68
1/7/2014,1837.88,4153.18
1/8/2014,1837.49,4165.61
1/9/2014,1838.13,4156.19
1/10/2014,1842.37,4174.67
1/13/2014,1819.2,4113.3
1/14/2014,1838.88,4183.02
1/15/2014,1848.38,4214.88
1/16/2014,1845.89,4218.69
1/17/2014,1838.7,4197.58
1/21/2014,1843.8,4225.76
1/22/2014,1844.86,4243
1/23/2014,1828.46,4218.88
1/24/2014,1790.29,4128.17
1/27/2014,1781.56,4083.61
1/28/2014,1792.5,4097.96
1/29/2014,1774.2,4051.43
1/30/2014,1794.19,4123.13
1/31/2014,1782.59,4103.88
2/3/2014,1741.89,3996.96
2/4/2014,1755.2,4031.52
2/5/2014,1751.64,4011.55
2/6/2014,1773.43,4057.12
2/7/2014,1797.02,4125.86`
    };

    const dataAdapter = new jqx.dataAdapter(source, {
      async: false,
      loadError: (xhr: any, status: any, error: any) => {
        console.log(xhr, status, error);
        //alert('Error loading "' + source.url + '" : ' + error);
      }
    });

    const columns: IGridProps["columns"] = [
      { cellsformat: "d", datafield: "Date", text: "Date", width: 250 },
      { datafield: "S&P 500", text: "S&P 500", width: 150 },
      { datafield: "NASDAQ", text: "NASDAQ" }
    ];
    const grid = (
      <JqxGrid
        ref={this.myGrid2}
        width={"100%"}
        height={400}
        source={dataAdapter}
        columns={columns}
        showtoolbar={true}
        rendertoolbar={this.state.rendertoolbar}
      />
    );
    render(grid, this.gridElementTwo.current!);
  };

  private saveBtntwo(): void {
    this.myWindowTWO.current!.hide();
  }

  private cancelBtntwo(): void {
    this.myWindowTWO.current!.hide();
  }

  private initWidgets = (tab: any) => {
    switch (tab) {
      case 0:
        this.initGrid();
        break;
      case 1:
        this.initGrid2();
        break;
    }
  };

  private onTabSelected = (event: any) => {
    switch (event.args.item) {
      case 0:
        // this.hideButton();
        break;
      case 1:
        //  this.showButton();
        break;
    }
  };
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

In the editor, on line #344, I have the following function defined:

```
private saveBtn(): void {
    const row = {
     sAndP500:this.sAndP500.current!.getOptions('value'),
     date:this.date.current!.getOptions('value')

    }
    console.log("Testing Row inside SaveBtn");
    console.log(row);
    this.myWindow.current!.hide();
  }
```

Using `sAndP500:this.sAndP500.current!.getOptions('value')` and       `date:this.date.current!.getOptions('value')` is the way to get whatever values are entered by the user in the `Add` window and when save button gets clicked.

I'm wondering, let's say on Line #208 in the editor if I want to have a default value for `sAndP500` and not the user input value as shown in the following line of code:

```
            <tr>
               <td align={"right"}>S & P 500:</td>
                  <td align={"left"}>
                    <JqxInput ref={this.sAndP500} width={150} height={23} />
                  </td>
                </tr>
```

So, I would modify the above code like this if I'm doing it correctly(basically changed `ref={this.sAndP500}` to  `value={20}`)
:

```
 <tr>
                  <td align={"right"}>S & P 500:</td>
                  <td align={"left"}>
                    <JqxInput value={20} width={150} height={23} />
                  </td>
                </tr>
```

And then I'm wondering, how should I get the value `20` inside the `saveBtn()` function because I won't be able to use `this.sAndP500.current!.getOptions('value')` anymore

```
private saveBtn(): void {
        const row = {
         //sAndP500:this.sAndP500.current!.getOptions('value'), // Can't use this anymore
         date:this.date.current!.getOptions('value')

        }
        console.log("Testing Row inside SaveBtn");
        console.log(row);
        this.myWindow.current!.hide();
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save input values inside the local state and whenever you press "Save" button you can get those data from the state.

Also, my suggestion would be: 
1. To don't create such a huge component, split and create reusable components as much as you can (maybe this was only for reviewers but still)
2. Also, try to don't use refs often, here is documentation and suggestions about that - [Don't overuse refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks. I'm wondering how do I retrieve that value here `const row = {}` when user clicks on add button and press  "Save" button. I may not need to save it in local state as I just want to pass that value to a web service call as soon as user press `save` button, which I haven't shown above.

Comment: I am glad if my comment was helpful ^^.